# callback for jquery mobile textarea resize

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, textarea

I am looking to hook a callback AFTER a textarea changes size using jquery mobile. As an example, I have the following:

```
        $('#test-textarea').val(BigTextVar).css('height', 'auto').trigger('change');
```

When this is hit, I want to run a function to resize div's above and below to accommodate the new height.

I tried adding a function to .trigger('change') but it happens BEFORE resize and not after. The same for .on('resize').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you trigger the resize event and then handle it:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ 

    $('#test-textarea').on("resize", function(e){
        alert("height = " + $(this).outerHeight());
    });

    $('#test-textarea').val(BigTextVar).css('height', 'auto').textinput( "refresh" ).resize();

});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9getxko6/)**

If you have timing issues, you could use a setTimeout to delay the resize trigger.